# Get a record count into root JSON path without it repeating?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, datatables

Gleaning several articles online, including this one [with a CTE](http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2015/08/jquery-datatables-stored-procedure-for.html), and this one [WITHOUT a CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52959529/3772763), I have been successful in getting the data I need, including a count of the results.  However, I need this count to be in a specific place in the JSON object...  Basically, I know how to get a rowset into a specific JSON structure with `FOR JSON PATH, ROOT ('data')`, etc.

However, I do not know how to get the "recordsFiltered" into the root of my JSON output.  This count is is derived using `COUNT(*) OVER () AS recordsFiltered`

Basically, I need my structure to look like this (see below)... How do I get "recordsFiltered" into the root `$.` of the JSON result without it repeating a billion times under the `"data":[]` section?

The best idea I can come up with is to create a temporary table, and then use *that* to structure the JSON.  But, I want to do it the fancy SQL way, if one exists, using SELECT statements or CTEs where applicable.

```
{
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 57, 
    "recordsFiltered": 57,  // <<<--- need records filtered HERE
    "data": [
        {
            "DT_RowId": "row_3",
            "recordsFiltered": "69,420",  //  <<<---- NOT HERE!!!
            "first_name": "Angelica",
            "last_name": "Ramos",
            "position": "System Architect",
            "office": "London",
            "start_date": "9th Oct 09",
            "salary": "$2,875"
        },

        ...
    ]
}
```

Here is the example SQL code:

```
 SELECT 
    COUNT(*) OVER () AS recordsFiltered,
    id,
    a,
    b
FROM t1
WHERE 
    (@Search IS NULL OR 
     id LIKE '%'+@Search+'%' OR 
     a LIKE '%'+@Search+'%' OR 
     b LIKE '%'+@Search+'%')
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN 
            CASE @SortCol
                WHEN 0 THEN id
                WHEN 1 THEN a
                WHEN 2 THEN b
            END 
        END desc,
    CASE 
        WHEN @SortDir = 'desc' THEN 
            CASE @SortCol
                WHEN 0 THEN id
                WHEN 1 THEN a
                WHEN 2 THEN b
            END 
        END DESC
OFFSET @DisplayStart ROWS
FETCH NEXT @DisplayLength ROWS ONLY
for json path, root ('data')
```

Comment: looks like you need to use a sub-select https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45698902/return-sql-server-database-query-with-nested-json

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to generate your table results, then use two (or more?) sub-queries

Here's a simplified example:

```
declare @tbl table (ID int identity, Col1 varchar(50), Col2 int)

insert into @tbl (Col1, Col2) values ('A',1),('B',2),('C',3)

select
    (select count(1) from @tbl) as 'total',
    (select * from @tbl for json path) as 'data'
for json path
```

produces:

```
[
    {
        "total": 3,
        "data": [
            {
                "ID": 1,
                "Col1": "A",
                "Col2": 1
            },
            {
                "ID": 2,
                "Col1": "B",
                "Col2": 2
            },
            {
                "ID": 3,
                "Col1": "C",
                "Col2": 3
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Without knowing the rest of your code/schema, here's my guess at your needed query:

```
select
    *
into
    #MyTable
from
    t1
WHERE 
    (@Search IS NULL OR 
     id LIKE '%'+@Search+'%' OR 
     a LIKE '%'+@Search+'%' OR 
     b LIKE '%'+@Search+'%')

select
    (select count(*) from #MyTable) as recordsFiltered,
    (
        select
            id,
            a,
            b
        from
            #MyTable
        ORDER BY
            CASE 
                WHEN @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN 
                    CASE @SortCol
                        WHEN 0 THEN id
                        WHEN 1 THEN a
                        WHEN 2 THEN b
                    END 
                END desc,
            CASE 
                WHEN @SortDir = 'desc' THEN 
                    CASE @SortCol
                        WHEN 0 THEN id
                        WHEN 1 THEN a
                        WHEN 2 THEN b
                    END 
                END DESC
        OFFSET @DisplayStart ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @DisplayLength ROWS ONLY
        for json path
    ) as [data]
for json path
```

Using a CTE:

```
with cte as ()
select
    *
from
    t1
WHERE 
    (@Search IS NULL OR 
     id LIKE '%'+@Search+'%' OR 
     a LIKE '%'+@Search+'%' OR 
     b LIKE '%'+@Search+'%')
)
select
    (select count(*) from cte) as recordsFiltered,
    (
        select
            id,
            a,
            b
        from
            cte
        ORDER BY
            CASE 
                WHEN @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN 
                    CASE @SortCol
                        WHEN 0 THEN id
                        WHEN 1 THEN a
                        WHEN 2 THEN b
                    END 
                END desc,
            CASE 
                WHEN @SortDir = 'desc' THEN 
                    CASE @SortCol
                        WHEN 0 THEN id
                        WHEN 1 THEN a
                        WHEN 2 THEN b
                    END 
                END DESC
        OFFSET @DisplayStart ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @DisplayLength ROWS ONLY
        for json path
    ) as [data]
for json path
```

Comment: Okay, so you're thinking that the only way to do this is with a temp table, right?  Because that was the best idea I could dome up with!?

Comment: You could use a CTE as well, I'm not sure which would perform best. It would likely depend on your table size, indexes, etc.

Comment: I've added an example with a CTE